# Why are certain vertices not affected by weight paint?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify, vertex-weights

Why don't these vertices move? I assigned everything there to be red yet it still does not move.

[image]

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YyeTx2cl7bzFB_YIuSEA9T5xMXv10VX9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is red, but only if you check the "Boots" vertex group. However if you would remove that group on the boot, it would still be posed by the armature - because the boot and shin armor are posed by weights on the "DEF-..." vertex groups. The buckles which are not moving have no weight assigned for these groups, they show blue there.